# node+mysql+express+ejs=double callbacks?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

When I open localhost/news/1 in my browser I can see that in console "1" appears two times, so I get sort of double callback. The problem is that after 2nd "1" in console node says that rows[0] is not defined even though it's defined and page was rendered using values from rows[0]. Then node crashes. Any ideas? :(

Here's the code:

```js
app.get('/news/:id', function(req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id` = '+req.params.id, function(err, rows) {
    res.render('news', {
        newsItem: rows[0]
    });
  });
});
```

Here's news.ejs:

```js
<%= console.log("1"); %>
<%= newsItem.title %>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling debugging for Express? Perhaps it could be a `favicon.ico` request that's crashing your application?

Comment: Does rows always have a length >= 1?

Comment: Nope, it's not favicon, And yes, array length is always >= 1.